# How do I convert a string to a class method? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is how to convert a string to a class in Rails/Ruby:

```
p = "Post"
Kernel.const_get(p)
eval(p)
p.constantize
```

But what if I am retrieving a method from an array/active record object like:

```
Post.description
```

but it could be

```
Post.anything
```

where anything is a string like `anything = "description"`.

This is helpful since I want to refactor a very large class and reduce lines of code and repetition. How can I make it work?

Comment: you realize you only need one of {const_get, eval, constantize}, right?

Comment: yes. of course i do. as I just tested the 3.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
Post.send(anything)
```

Comment: working perfectly, thanks. reduced so many lines of code to just a few.

Comment: if my method is like: def test=(string){puts string }. I dont think Post.send("test", "hi") will work fine..

Comment: It's safer to use [`Post.public_send(:anything)`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send) (Ruby 1.9 or later)

Answer (score 18):

While eval can be a useful tool for this sort of thing, and those from other backgrounds may take to using it as often as one might a can opener, it's actually dangerous to use so casually. Eval implies that anything can happen if you're not careful.

A safer method is this:

```
on_class = "Post"
on_class.constantize.send("method_name")
on_class.constantize.send("method_name", arg1)
```

Object#send will call whatever method you want. You can send either a Symbol or a String and provided the method isn't private or protected, should work.

Comment: This is already executing arbitrary methods. Security doesn't seem to be a major factor here.

Comment: Arbitrary methods are a lot different from arbitrary code. I doubt you have a "DROP ALL TABLES" method on your class. It's also elementary to verify that a given string is safe or not to use as a method name, you can have a simple white-list to check, however evaluating the danger of an arbitrary eval block is impossible.

Answer (score 16):

Since this is taged as a Ruby on Rails question, I'll elaborate just a little.

In Rails 3, assuming `title` is the name of a field on an ActiveRecord object, then the following is also valid:

```
@post = Post.new
method = "title"

@post.send(method)                # => @post.title
@post.send("#{method}=","New Name") # => @post.title = "New Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Test
 def method_missing(id, *args)
   puts "#{id} - get your method name"
   puts "#{args} - get values"
 end
end

a = Test.new
a.name('123')
```

So the general syntax would be `a.<anything>(<any argument>)`.