# extract string of method names from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am trying something new and I'm stubborn, so I want to exhaust all possibilities.

I have a model called navbar with a field for links.

Inside the links field, I have stored a number of words:

```
profile_link community_link
```

The words are significant, in that, they are also the names of methods I have recorded in navbars_helper:

```
module NavbarsHelper
  def profile_link
    link_to current_user do
      image_tag(current_user.image.img.mini_avatar)
      current_user.name
    end
  end
  def community_link
    link_to 'Community', topics_path
  end
 ...
end
```

The new thing I was trying, was to extract the words from the string and use them to call the methods in my header layout:

```
 - if signed_in?
      - @current_group.navbars do |navbar|
        - if navbar.kind == "Header"
          = navbar.links.to_s
```

navbar belongs_to group

So, what I get is the string in the header: profile_link community_link

But, what I want is a call to the methods. Is this possible? If so, can you tell me how you would do it?

I'm not very experienced working with arrays and I think it may have something to do with

Comment: Something like this always runs through my head at some point but I always knock it. I always take it for a bad smell

Comment: It looks like .send may be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913566/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-class-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that it could be made working, although I am not really sure if it is worth: you are adding a lot of complexity for almost no additional benefit.

Said that, something along the lines of

```
- if signed_in?     
  - @current_group.navbars.each do |navbar|
    - if navbar.kind == "Header"
      - navbar.links.split(' ').each do |method|
        = self.send(method)
```

Basically, take the string `"profile_link community_link"`, split it using the space character and then send each method to the view (which is `self` in this context). Using `send` just executes the method as you would do normally, but gives you the benefit of deciding which method to execute at runtime :)