# How to use a rails variable when accessing a YAML path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'm trying to make a generic method that takes my Rails variable (which corresponds to a YAML key) and get the YAML data.

#### settings.yml

```
features:
  first_feature: true
  second_feature: false
```

#### Rails function

```
def my_function(feature)
  Settings.features.#{feature} # where #{feature} passes my param
end
```

#### Example Use:

```
my_function(first_feature)
# => true
```

Not sure if this is possible -- haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: @Jordan `Settings` references the settings.yml and the chained method finds `features` in settings.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on [How do I convert a string to a class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913566/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-class-method)

Using `.send(variable)` works. So:

```
def my_function(feature)
  Settings.features.send(feature)
end
```